# Having trouble with a query. DBMS Assignment

Tags: oracle

Working on an assignment for school, was able to figure out all but this one.

I need to display the employee name and employee identification number along with their HOD's name and identification number.
The table is structured like this:

```
(TABLE NAME): EMPLOYEES

EMPLOYEE_ID  
EMPLOYEE_NAME  
HOD (which is an EMPLOYEE_ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, you can join a table to itself.
Treat the two sides of the join as two separate tables and you're on your way to solving it.

Comment: I've done a few joins with two different tables. My brain isn't quite getting the joining to itself.

Comment: Do you talk about the specific join of this task or joins in general?

Comment: Also You can use a correlated subquery in the select-list.
`SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, 
        EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
        HOD, 
       (SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME 
          FROM EMPLOYEES 
         WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = A.EMPLOYEE_ID) HOD_NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE A;`
 But I'm sure your teacher it's trying to teach you the simple self-join way